# exclude auto merging for certain files doing git pull?

Tags: git, github

The conflict is too large for a file when I do git pull, how to use the latest code from remote? exclude it from merging my version, because I want to manually add it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge and take the file from the other branch:

```
git merge/pull/whatever
git checkout other-branch -- the-file
```